# how to loop though an html table rows and put them in an array

Tags: php, arrays, dom

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery))
{
echo "<tr> <td>$row[Name]</td><td> $row[Number]</td><td> $row[MyDateCol]</td><td>$row[MyCheckboxCol]</td></tr>";
}
```

I am trying to learn some basic php and i am populating an html table with rows from a database table with code above.

Now I want on button submit to convert all data row values into a php array which I can then manipulate. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Uhm, you know that php is executed on server side and the DOM tree is located on clientside browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTML table can't be submitted, if you want to do that you should work with a form. Apart from that, it's much easier to create the array while fetching the database rows, like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'name' => $row['Name'],
        'number' => $row['Number'],
        'myDateCol' => $row['MyDateCol'],
        'myCheckboxCol' => $row['MyCheckboxCol']
    );
}
```

Comment: Now if I change any of the column values in the browser how would I update my array with the latest values/changes made?\

Comment: Well, it depends on how you send the data to the server after changing the column values in the browser. As I said before, if you want to submit user data you should be using a form and not a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$emptyArray = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery))  {

echo "<tr> <td>$row[Name]</td><td> $row[Number]</td><td> $row[MyDateCol]</td>      
<td>$row[MyCheckboxCol]</td></tr>";

$emptyArray['Name'] = $row['Name']
$emptyArray['Number'] = $row['Number']
$emptyArray['MyDateCol'] = $row['MyDateCol']
$emptyArray['MyCheckboxCol'] = $row['MyCheckboxCol']
}
```

now you can use this

```
$emptyArray
```

Comment: I need to get the array data from the html table but not from $sqlquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate HTML data using PHP, because PHP is run server-side. You must manipulate it with a client-side language like javascript. Using it, you can add symbols to the data so it ressembles a PHP array representation and pass it to the server, if you want :)